# Checkbox and Select Options update a Total Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox

I have to create a small calculator form by using checkboxes and a select field.

If the user clicks on two checkboxes the select field will update to the option 2 and the total will update to a total figure of 456

Here is my HTML

```
<div>
<label for="one">1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1" value="228" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="two">2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="2" id="2" value="228" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="three">3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="3" id="3" value="228" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="four">4</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="4" id="4" value="228" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="five">5</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="5" id="5" value="228" />
</div>

<select>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="Total" value="Total">
```

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/barrycorrigan/se21b1p6/1/

I'm just not sure how to create this in jquery. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look into `.change` events to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works:

```
$(function() {
    var total = $("input[name='Total']");
    var checkBox = $("input[type='checkbox']");
    var _select = $("select");
    checkBox.click(function(){
        checkBox.prop("checked", false);
        var _index = $(this).attr("id")
        total.val(_index * 228);
        _select.val(_index);
        checkBox.each(function(){
            if (_index > 0) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                _index--;
            }
        });
    });
    _select.change(function() {
        checkBox.prop("checked", false);
        var _val = $(this).val();
        total.val(_val * 228);
        checkBox.each(function() {
            if (_val > 0) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                _val--;
            }
        });       
    });  
});
```

You can see it in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yuanzm/se21b1p6/6/

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks. What about using the select field. If you select 5 from the select list the 5 checkboxes will be checked and the total will appear. This is amazing and really appreciate the help

Comment: You are welcome~I update the answer,you can see the changes.Hope can help you~

Comment: My pleasure~ If you have another questions about jQuery,you can also ask me

Comment: One more question, if you look at the example [http://www.intrawestpassport.com/#purchase](http://www.intrawestpassport.com/#purchase) if a customer selects the 5th icon(checkbox) they all get selected. Same if you select 2 the first two get select. Is there anyway we can add this to your example. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes,the same with select field.See the newest answer~

Comment: Really appreciate that.. Amazing!!

Comment: I have been working on this and it has been great. One thing though when the totals are generated in the text box is there anyway we can have them as an actual value. Because when you click on it the value just disappears.

Comment: I'm sorry,I can't get the point.You mean you want to get the total value after every click?

Comment: I got it sorted, I was trying to use the calx plugin for calculations, that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this also

```
     var countChecked = function() {
     var n = $( "input:checked" ).length; 

  $('select >option:eq('+ n +')').prop('selected', true);
      sum();

 };
countChecked();
function sum() {
var inputs = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked'),
    result = $('#total'),
    sum = 0;            

for(var i=0; i< $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length; i++) {
    var ip = inputs[i];

    if (ip.name && ip.name.indexOf("total") < 0) {
        sum += parseInt(ip.value) || 0;
    }

}

$(result).val(sum);
  } 
 $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amolks/yfat78rL/